# Remap Super Key

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, shortcut-keys

Is there a way to remap the Super Key to another location, like the Scroll lock key? I didn't see something like this in settings, I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, LTS, but I think this is a fairly general question(I can always give more information).

Comment: You mean to also bind super key to something else?

Comment: I believe so, I want to make my scroll lock key my super key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> key as <kbd>Super</kbd> key, run this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key 'Scroll_Lock'
```

To go back run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key 'Super_L'
```